# How to resign given the situation?

Tags: software-industry, resignation, human-resources, canada

I've been offered a job at a better company with a much higher salary. I'll be signing the employment agreement sometime this week.

Anyways, if you've read my whole slew of other posts about my current workplace then I think resigning without drama is a key thing here.

After all the comments and uncomfortable conversations I'm not on the best of terms with my manager and HR.

The CEO of the company is my former manager (he got promoted during my time here) and he is actually the main head of the office but he's not in everyday. HR and my other manager are both in the office everyday but they aren't exactly my boss or 'in charge' if you know what I mean. It's a small office with just 12 people here.

I was thinking of sending out a respectful resignation notice email to all 3 of them but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about it. I could do it in person to just the 2 of them but the CEO may not be around that week etc.

How would you handle this? Is it better to do it in person? Send out an email then have a meeting?

Also, according to Canadian law I only have to give 2 weeks notice because I'm not at a senior level. My employment contract says that I've to give 4 weeks notice. I've run out of vacation time too. The new place needs me to start in 3 weeks. I'm sure this won't go over well with the people I'm not on good terms with.

Edits:
I've done some more research and according to the law in British Columbia an employee is not required to give any notice at all if they would like to terminate their employment. I also haven't resigned my employment agreement since starting there over 2 years ago.

Comment: Tell them you'd like to be done in 2 weeks so you have 1 week off, compromise at 3 if they really insist.

Comment: Ending a long-term relationship, whether personal or professional, should happen face-to-face whenever possible. It's almost never comfortable. It's still better than the so-called "text message breakup."

Comment: In a company large enough for you to have a manager and an HR person, even if it's only 12 people, I don't see the need to announce your resignation with the CEO, is there any particular reason for that other than him being your former manager?

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, you'd need to check with an actual lawyer whether the notice period you mention is legally binding or not. If it's an actual signed, legal and still valid employment contract they might hold you to it (but what can they do, fire you?). If it's just their employee handbook than you shouldn't have a problem giving your standard 2 weeks. Bear in mind that IANAL applies and this is advice I've seen given in an American context, you'd really need to check that with a lawyer or do some digging.

Comment: @Air, I'm sure the managers will get over it. No need for a face-to-face in parting of ways especially since, given the history with the OP, no one should be surprised.

Comment: @Lilienthal, I am sure that BEFORE contacting a lawyer the best thing to do is to just ask the employer if 2 weeks notice is OK. Contracts have all kinds of zany cruft in them and the parties involved often don't want the aggravation of sweating each detail.

Comment: @teego1967 For any other employer I would certainly agree, but OP has given a pretty good indication that no part of his notice period will go particularly smooth.

Comment: Have you handed everything over that you were working on?  Do you _need_ the extra time to document/hand over everything?  If you can show that you have (or will) completed everything to make sure a smooth transition of your duties, then that will put you in a stronger position to ask to shorten the notice period.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How would you handle this? Is it better to do it in person?

**The correct way is to speak *in person* with your current boss if at all possible, and tell her/him that you are resigning.** You also need to indicate your last day. You don't need to go into a lot of details in this. From your prior posts, it doesn't sound like your resignation would be completely unexpected anyway.

Your boss will then alert whoever else needs to know about your departure (HR, his boss, etc), and eventually tell you whatever else needs to be done before your last day. Some companies want a resignation letter or email that they can keep on file, some don't. Sometimes you will have an exit interview with HR, fill out some paperwork, perform some knowledge transfer with others, whip up some additional documentation, etc. Your boss (and potentially HR) will guide you in all of that.

In spite of your bad experiences, now is not the time to be less than professional.

If you still haven't run into your CEO (or others that you would like to know you are leaving), you could send out a "Goodbye" email on your last day.

Something along the lines of "As many of you know, today is my last day... I learned a lot here... I enjoyed working with you... I wish you all good luck and much success."

When I send such an email, I always include my personal contact information, so that people can continue to get in touch with me. You may not want to do that with everyone, since it appears you didn't get along with all of them, but perhaps there are one or two.

Answer (score 8):

The first question is really a matter of opinion.  If you arent on the best of terms with your manager and HR, there is no point in rocking the boat more than it needs to be.  Type up a resignation letter and give them a copy.  As for the CEO, that is entirely up to you and how you feel your relationship is.

The second question is really a matter for a HR specialist or lawyer for your jurisdiction.  What may be valid in one location, might not be true in another.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend the following:

- From the company policy, find out whom the resignation should be handed to (Reporting Manager/HR/someone else?). Given your history with the company, it is essential that you hand over your resignation to the right person, because they might try to cause you more trouble by calling your resignation "invalid" if you submit it to the wrong person.
- Meet this person face-to-face (or over video chat/phone, if face-to-face is not feasible), and inform them of your decision to resign. It is likely they will push you into discussing the reasons. Avoid complaining or saying anything negative, but don't go over-the-top singing praises of the company either (especially given your history with them). Assure them of your support in ensuring a smooth transition of your current work.
- After the meeting, send them an email resignation. "As discussed this morning, I wish to resign ...", etc. People have this habit of "forgetting" things which were verbally stated. This is particularly important for you given your history and your somewhat tight notice period constraint. You don't want to hear this 2 weeks later: "Hey, we talked about your resignation on the 25th, not 18th, so you still have one week of notice period left."
- Personally, I would avoid sending out resignation emails to any more people than are necessary. I would, of course, inform ex-coworkers, but not send my resignation mail to them. Your CEO *was* your manager, he is not your manager now. If he is required to be "officially" communicated of your resignation, I expect your manager (or HR) to deal with that.
- I am not qualified to answer questions about notice periods in Canada, but the general advice is to politely negotiate the notice period to what you want. Ensuring a smooth transition of your current work also helps with that.
- Further to the above point, I always throw in a variant of the following  in my resignation mails or meetings:

> I understand it is possible that some things might not get covered during the handover. Hence, if team members taking over my code run into problems after I have left, they are free to reach me by phone, and I will try to help them as much as I can.

This usually works like a charm during the notice period negotiations, while in reality, I have received *zero* phone calls until now.

Comment: Good answer. With regards to your final point, I have always made a _verbal_ offer like that, but I think I would avoid putting it in writing in an email or resignation letter. Just to avoid any potential unreasonable demands.

Comment: @Carson63000 Good point, I will include that point in the answer later today. I do not actually use such a "no holds barred" wording in my actual letter, but more like, "I am available for about the next 2 weeks for 15 minutes per day".